# When adding to source control, Visual Studio doesn't ask where to add the solution. How do I add my solution to the location I want?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I started a new project and decided to add it to source control (TFS).  When I right-click on the solution and choose `Add Solution to Source Control` Visual Studio automatically adds it to the top level directory of source control without prompting me on where to put it.  The solution has not been checked in yet.

I think what happened was the first time I tried this it asked me where I wanted to add the solution but I didn't select the correct spot.  Now when I undo pending changes and try again it always puts it in the same spot without asking.

Is there a way to start over?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the visual studio toolbar | file | source control | workspace | 
open the workspace you are using and remove the extra binding that got added because you prviously added the solution to source control.

Answer (score 2):

Once you added your solution to the source control, TFS memorizes the mapping of the location to the local path. To remove the mapping, open the Source Control Explorer window, right-click on the solution and choose "Remove Mapping".

You also may find this helpful: http://zayko.net/post/How-to-permanently-remove-TFS-Source-Control-association-bindings.aspx